# Need help retrieving my 40ETH

Tags: transactions, wallets

[image]

Hi All

I have made a major rookie mistake 2 days ago and would would it if one of you guys can help me out

I transferred 40 ETH into ETC using JAXX WALLET

Only to find out even though it is in the same wallet but they dont support each other - Is there anyway for me to retrieve this 40ETH - This thing has been occupying my mind for the past 2 days - Any direction from here would be wonderful I am willing to give a ether away for your time :)

Comment: And by the way, if you wish to send a tip in case you succeed using my instructions, be free to send ETH to 0x8Cd9f8f7F28dC2048d10710Ec169F4B462D314C5 but please note that I don't answer for money but for helping community.

Comment: It worked - thank you so much and gave you some ether your way just to say thank you for your time:)

Comment: You're welcome also could you please mark the answer as solved? Thanks.

Comment: I am going to sound like a rookie here but how would I mark it as solved ?

Comment: You should see a check mark bellow my answer number of upvotes. Just check it and while you are here upvote it ;) and thanks for the eth tip, I well received it, thank you very much.

Comment: NO thank you, I think I just upvoted it and frankly you saved me HOURS AND HOURS if not days of mucking around - I just went to myetherwallet like your instruction and did it in 5 mins

Comment: So good luck and keep working with ETH. It's the future!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably more easy than what you think.

- First, go to an explorer to check that **your etc account also exists in eth** chain: https://etherscan.io/address/0xc2a9d704e163806df8725c3c1829b7392623b21f
- Then go to your Jaxx wallet app menu. Go to tools and then diplay private keys. Select your **etc** wallet and copy the private key.
- finally go back to jaxx app menu, touch transfer paper wallet, past the private key and follow instructions. Don't forget to check that your ETH wallet is the target.
- if you can't or don't want to import your key with jaxx, you can use https://www.myetherwallet.com/#send-transaction . Past your private key, unlock the wallet, select the amount and target account and send your eth to your regular account.

Et voila, you should only have lost some transaction fees.

The key is that an Ethereum key is able to work on etc and eth as they use the same protocol. This is sometimes confusing but in this case it's a nice feature